# What data structure should I use where the key falls within a range?

Tags: data-structures

TL;DR: What data structure should I use for looking up key-value pairs where the key needs to fall within a range?

I'm looking for something like a `Dictionary` but with a twist. 
I have a HexEditor with lines, say 8 bytes per line (this can and does differ though).

Any byte within the memblock displayed by the hexeditor can have a comment.
One or zero Comments are associated with one byte-address.
Obviously a range of bytes can have multiple comments and if so all comments will be displayed on a line.
I thought about storing the comments in a `Dictionary<Int, String>` however that will not work, because I need to lookup if the comment falls within a range and a Dict only matches on exact matches. 
The range can change dynamically so I can't link to that either.

It is possible to change the number of bytes per line on the fly and I don't want to have to reconstitute the data store/recalculate all my hashes, so using a dictionary with start-end values as the key is out.

I don't want to do a query to the Dict for every byte in a line.
I suspect the answer is "binary tree" but I'm hoping for something a bit more O(1)ish.

Comment: You say that individual bytes can have associated comments. But also seem to imply that ranges of bytes can have associated comments. I can't quite tell whether the ranges are part of the underlying data structure, or only supplied by the user as part of their search query. I also don't follow the relevance of lines to the question. Surely grouping bytes in lines is just a convenience for display.  In short, I for one am confused!

Comment: Segemented Trees should do I guess!

Comment: @DavidHeffernan, one or zero comments link to a single byte-address. The ranges are just a consequence of how the data is displayed. 8 bytes per line or 4 bytes per line, or a differing number of bytes per line if in disassembly mode for a CPU that allows variable length instructions.

Comment: @kiner_shah, yes might work, as long as the rebuilt is fast.  If I allow only multiples of 4 as the width (when in fixed width mode), I can get away with pretending the width is 4 and do a lookup for the neighbors. If I make the tree threaded that's a O(1) operation. I can always decrease the lookup time cost by overlaying a wider spaced tree on top of a small spaced tree (at the expense of extra storage).

Answer (score 0):

Beware of O(1) when there is a high constant time involved, like is the case for hashed dictionaries, as the cost of hashing is never negligible.

Binary search (as in a binary tree or for an ordered list) is only O(log n), and log is a function that grows very slowly.

When looking up an Integer key, odds are you will be able to perform a score of comparisons in the same time it takes to compute a single hash, and a score of comparisons is enough to perform a binary search among a million elements.

Comment: I feel you are forgetting the overhead in memory access. Even a single cache miss will cost me more than the hash. The hash calculation does not suffer cache misses, because that code is hot. Obviously I'd need to replace BobJenkins with something faster. Still thanks for the consideration.

Comment: A cache miss is typically a dozen cycles, you will need a very case-specific hash if you want to beat that with a good hash (ie. without the potential for many collisions). Common fast hashes only reach low cycles count per bytes when hashing a large amounts of bytes. Also if you're worried about cache misses, hashes kinda maximize them for sequential lookups (like in your case), while a sorted list or binary tree would minimize them (contiguous indexes lead to contiguous data, and you would be accessing contiguous indexes more often than not)